# mvc multiselectlist not null when not selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc web form which has a multiselectlist ( i am using ListBoxFor) that i am posting to a controller from jquery.

When i select any value from my multiselectlist, it gets the right value and everything is working.

My multiselectlist is mapped to my model as a `List<string>` and when no value is selected, it has a count of `1` with element at `[0]` as an empty string.

I see that when jquery is posting, the value is posting as null.

Is there a way to automatically make my List on the model as a null ?

```
 $('#myButton').click(function (e) {

            var mlist= $("#multilist").val(); //get multilist values

            var v1,v2..=  //capture other values from other controls

            alert(mlist); //i get null here when not selected
            var postModel= {
                v1:...
                v2:..
                v3:mlist

            };

            $("#mydivelement").load('@Url.Action("PostAction","Home")', postModel);

 });
```

and my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostAction(MyModel postModel )
```

Comment: Can you show share the post being sent to server? null won't be converted to list with 1 element so there seems to be something you're not telling :)

Comment: Can we see your JQ too?

Comment: I updated it...

Comment: should i map to `string[]` instead of `List<string>` on model ?